# save all parse results into one map in scala

Tags: scala, parsing

Suppose I've got following txt file:

```
--quest_29540602496284069
Operator Name : Kevin
Account Id: 1444

Text: This is Kevin and this my text.
Age: 16
--quest_=29540602496284069--
```

I want to transform it to simple scala map:

```
(pseudo-code)
{
  quest_id: 29540602496284069
  operation_name = Kevin 
  account_id: 1444
  text: This is Kevin and this my text.
  operator_age: 16
}
```

So, i started to created case content class in order to store it in target object for future use:

```
case class MapContent(map: Map[String, String])
```

Then, i have created scala class with extending RegexpParsers:

```
class OperatorParser extends RegexParsers {

  def parseFullRequest(input: String): MapContent = parseAll(parseRequest, input) match {
    case Success(result, _) => result
    case NoSuccess(msg, _) => throw new SomeParserException(msg)
  }

  // main entry
  def parseRequest: Parser[MapContent] = parseQuestBody ~ parseAnotherBody

  def parseQuestBody: Parser[MapContent] = parseQuestId

  def parseQuestId: Parser[MapContent] = "--quest_" ~> """.+\n?""".r ^^ { case res =>
    MapContent(Map("quest_id" -> res.toString))
  }

  def parseAnotherBody: Parser[MapContent] = """.+""".r ^^ { case res =>
    MapContent(Map("another_body" -> res.toString))
  }

}
```

When i'm doing

```
parseQuestBody ~ parseAnotherBody
```

it causes an error that Operator[MapContent, MapContent] isn't an Operator[MapContent]

I need a solution how to store exactly in MapContent during the whole parse process. Is there a possible way to do that? For now i can only store the **quest_id** number and not able to continue next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^^` like in other parsers:

```
def parseRequest: Parser[MapContent] = parseQuestBody ~ parseAnotherBody ^^ {
    case res => MapContent(res._1.map ++ res._2.map)
}
```

or

```
def parseRequest: Parser[MapContent] = parseQuestBody ~ parseAnotherBody ^^ {
    case a ~ b => MapContent(a.map ++ b.map)
}
```

It transforms "tuple" of `MapContents` into single `MapContent`

Edit:

> what if i will have a lot of text values, so in scala it will be
>   looking like a.map ++ b.map ++ c.map ++ d... + f.. + ... + x1 ? is
>   there more common way?

Folding it is one of possibilities:

```
def parseRequest: Parser[MapContent] = parseQuestId ~ rep(parseAnotherBody) ~ parseQuestId ^^ {
    case value1 ~ list1 ~ value2=> {
      val merged = List(value1, value2) ++ list1
      merged.foldLeft(MapContent(Map.empty[String, String]))((a, b) => MapContent(a.map ++ b.map))
    }
  }
```

It returns map with only 2 values because you can't store in map 2 values with same `another_body` key

Comment: what if i will have a lot of text values, so in scala it will be looking like a.map ++ b.map ++ c.map ++ d... + f.. + ... + x1 ? is there more common way?

Comment: every example still doesn't compile with "cannot resolve symbol map" error

Comment: can you help please? i'd like to use your example but don't know how to transform the map to correct situation

Comment: Here is my code, http://ideone.com/a1ldsg, i don't know why it doesn't work for you, what's your scala version?

Comment: thanks for the response - your code is compiling well and you use the 3rd option, but how about 1st and 2nd? does it compile on your side?

Comment: I used this code with simplified input, to be exact, two first lines of your input, so with normal input i have `string matching regex `\z' expected but `A' found` as you probably do.